# Using foreach in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the below array `em_events(array(` and need to insert the below foreach to repeat the `$delete` link. How do in put a foreach into an array? Not sure how best to describe this.

```
foreach ($EM_Events as $event) {
    $delete = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('action'=>'event_delete', 'event_id'=>$event->event_id, '_wpnonce'=> wp_create_nonce('event_delete_'.$event->event_id))));
}


    em_events(array(
    'owner'=>4,
    'limit'=>10,
    'scope'=>'all',
    'format'=>'

<li class="even portfolio-entry">
    <div class="entry-thumb standard">
        <a class="thumblink" href="'.$delete.'"><span class="thumbnail">#_EVENTIMAGE{220,220}</span><span class="extra"><strong>Edit Event</strong></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="entry-title">
        <a href="#_EVENTURL" title="#_EVENTURL" rel="bookmark"><span style="color:#00b1d9;">PREVIEW EVENT POST</span><span>#F #j, #Y</span>#_NAME</a>
    </div>
</li>   

    '
     ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going in a completely different direction with this. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
foreach ($EM_Events as $event) {
    $delete = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('action'=>'event_delete', 'event_id'=>$event->event_id, '_wpnonce'=> wp_create_nonce('event_delete_'.$event->event_id))));



    em_events(array(
    'owner'=>4,
    'limit'=>10,
    'scope'=>'all',
    'format'=>'

  <li class="even portfolio-entry">
      <div class="entry-thumb standard">
          <a class="thumblink" href="'.$delete.'"><span class="thumbnail">#_EVENTIMAGE{220,220}</span><span class="extra"><strong>Edit Event</strong></span></a>
      </div>

      <div class="entry-title">
          <a href="#_EVENTURL" title="#_EVENTURL" rel="bookmark"><span style="color:#00b1d9;">PREVIEW EVENT POST</span><span>#F #j, #Y</span>#_NAME</a>
      </div>
  </li>'
     ));
}
```

Comment: This repeats the `em_events(array` for as many times as their are `$EM_Events`.  In this case 4 times.  Basically I need `em_events(array` to show up once but the <li> to repeat over `$EM_Events`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$format=NULL;
foreach ($EM_Events as $event) {
            $delete = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('action'=>'event_delete', 'event_id'=>$event->event_id, '_wpnonce'=> wp_create_nonce('event_delete_'.$event->event_id))));

$format=$format.
'<li class="even portfolio-entry">
    <div class="entry-thumb standard">
        <a class="thumblink" href="'.$delete.'"><span class="thumbnail">#_EVENTIMAGE{220,220}</span><span class="extra"><strong>Edit Event</strong></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="entry-title">
        <a href="#_EVENTURL" title="#_EVENTURL" rel="bookmark"><span style="color:#00b1d9;">PREVIEW EVENT POST</span><span>#F #j, #Y</span>#_NAME</a>
    </div>
</li>';   
}

em_events(array(
'owner'=>4,
'limit'=>10,
'scope'=>'all',
'format'=>$format,
 ));
```